# How do I get scanner to work with the arrays

Tags: java

Create ten accounts in an array with id 0, 1, 2 ...9, and initial balance $50.  The system prompts the user to enter an id.  If the id is entered incorrectly, ask the user to enter a correct id

This is what I have so far am stuck as to how to get scanner to work with the arrays

```
package Object_1_Programs;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class Accounts_Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        //declare arrays
        int [] a=new int[9];



        double balance=50;

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Your ID:");
        a[id]=input.nextInt();



    }

}
```

Any help will do thanks

Comment: Consider using a [loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: You're not being asked to fill an array of 9 integers with the user input. You're being asked to create an array of 10 Account objects, each Account having an ID and a balance, and to get an ID from the user input.

Comment: am new an how do i do that

Comment: I'm sure you have a Java book. Read it. The teacher wouldn't ask you to do that without having introduced you to the necessary concepts. And we won't do your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get ID into a var:

```
int id = input.nextInt();
```

Then you need to iterate over your array to compare each element if it equals your received id e.g.

```
boolean idFound = false;
for(int arrayID : a)
{
  if (arrayID == id)
  {
    idFound=true;
    // found id in the array ... do your logic here
  }
}
if (!idFound)
{
  // ID not found...ask about new id
}
```